# Prove that is mapping is a isomorphism between probability spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

For $I$ countable, let $\Omega = \prod_{\alpha \in I} \Omega_{\alpha}$ be a cartesian product of sets $\Omega_{\alpha}$ and $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be a family of mappings $X_{\alpha}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $X_{\alpha}(\omega) = \omega_{\alpha}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in which every such $X_{\alpha}$ is measurable. Suppose we have another space $\Omega'$, another set of functions $X_{\alpha}': \Omega' \to \mathbb{R}$, and another $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}'$ which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra in which every mapping $X_{\alpha}'$ is measurable. We have two probability measures $\mu$ and $\mu'$, so that both $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mu')$ become probability spaces.

Let $U: L^{2}(\Omega,d\mu) \to L(\Omega',d\mu')$ be a unitary map which maps characteristic functions to characteristic functions. That is, if $E \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\chi_{E}(x)$ is the characteristic function of $E$ (i.e. $\chi_{E}(x) = 1$ if $x \in E$ and zero otherwise) then $U\chi_{E} = \chi_{E'}$ for some $E' \in \mathcal{F}'$. Define a mapping $T: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}'$ by setting $U\chi_{E} = \chi_{T(E)}$.

My question is the following. I want to know if $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mu')$ are isomorphic as measure spaces. Hence, I need a mapping from $\Omega$ to $\Omega'$ which preserves measurable sets, but I only have a mapping $T$ which maps $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathcal{F}'$. Does $T$ induce another map, say, $f: \Omega \to \Omega'$ under which the desired isomorphism is proven? My idea would be to define $f$ by $f(\omega) := T(\{\omega\})$. The problem is: I am not sure if singletons $\{\omega\}$ belong to $\mathcal{F}$. I believe so, because it is the countable intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}X_{\alpha}^{-1}(x)$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: What is $X$ and $X'$? Did you mean $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$?

Comment: Ops, Yes! Thanks!